# Outros sites da rede StackExchange não poderiam ter a versão em português?

Tags: debate

Na versão original do **Stack**, existe vários sites como por exemplo: *MathOverflow, Area 51, Christianity, Chemistry* e muitos outros.

Por que não expandir alguns dos principais sites da rede, também para o português? Acredito que serviria de grande uso por nós, já usuários do Stack e também para quem ainda não conhece como professores, estudantes e entusiastas.

O StackOverFlow em português deu um grande retorno de membros, por que não expandir?

Comment: Isso daí já deu uma discussão boa, a resposta curta é **"Não"**. A resposta longa está espalhada pelo meta, pode ver [nesse tópico](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2482/3117) e [nesse](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3867/3117) ou pelos resultados [dessa busca](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=super+user) dentre outras do gênero.

Comment: A SO/SE diz não ter recursos tecnicos (ou interesse) em abrir novos sites em diferentes linguas, as propostas para SO em outras linguas como coreano foram fechadas, eles dizem que não previsão para lançar novos sites mas uma hora voltam. Outras versões do SO são em japones, russo e espanhol.

Comment: [Internationalization 'State of the Stack'](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/q/20987/56531)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Um dia vamos ter outros sites em português mas *dificilmente* vamos ter algo similar à [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com), basicamente por não ser possível sustentar um crescimento indeterminado de sites em outras línguas.

Atualmente - contando por baixo as áreas de comunidade, design e desenvolvimento - somos em torno de 70 pessoas tomando conta de 149 sites em inglês e 4 em outras línguas. É necessário muita gente pra manter esse circo na estrada. E partes em *não-inglês* dependem de mão de obra "especializada" se quisermos fazer as coisas direito.

Mesmo tendo apenas 1 site pra cada língua diferente, e cada um desses sites com uma pessoa exclusivamente responsável por tomar conta dele, eis a quantidade de coisas que ainda não funcionam:

- Não sabemos como dar atenção devida aos Metas internacionais
- Não temos um processo correto e bem definido de resolver bugs
- Não temos um processo minimamente funcional de apoio às traduções e aos tradutores
- Não temos planos concretos de como ou quando novas funcionalidades (Careers, Docs, Teams, etc) vão aparecer nos SO internacionais
- Não temos estratégia de marketing
- Não sabemos como e quando monetizar esses sites

Cada um desses pontos se divide em mais vários outros que também não temos, ou não sabemos, como resolver ainda.

*Abrir* um site em outra língua não dá trabalho algum. *Manter* um site em outra língua dá muito, muito trabalho se quisermos fazer direito. E **sempre** vamos querer fazer direito.

Todas as comunidades internacionais sofrem um pouco por causa, principalmente, dos 4 primeiros pontos e isso não é justo. E seria ainda menos justo com as próximas comunidades internacionais se déssemos à elas a chance de existir, mas não o suporte para continuar existindo.

Nós continuamos tentando encontrar soluções pra esses problemas. Esse é praticamente todo o foco do time internacional no momento: como fazer com que as comunidades internacionais sejam ouvidas e suas necessidades sejam atendidas. Não acontece do dia pra noite, e nós nem sempre vamos ter novidades fresquinhas pra contar, mas continua sendo nosso principal objetivo.

O que foi dito no [International State of the Stack](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20987) continua valendo. Já demos vários passos para melhorar as coisas desde que aquele post foi escrito, e devemos escrever um novo em breve.

Atualmente quase todo foco da empresa está nas nossas novas ferramentas (principalmente Docs e Teams) o que significa que sites internacionais vão ter que esperar mais um pouco até podermos nos dedicar de verdade em resolver os problemas que afetam seu dia a dia. Mas vamos sempre deixar vocês por dentro do que está acontecendo. E se não deixarmos, basta perguntar.

Comment: Apesar de todos os poréns, nunca tinha visto vocês dizerem com tanta firmeza que "um dia vamos ter outros sites em português".

Comment: @bfavaretto Quando dizemos "queremos ter o Super User, mas não agora", estamos falando sério ;)

Comment: @bfavaretto - sorry for writing in English. I am also very excited about this possibility. This is something that must be done responsibly, we must be able to plan for success, so that we can support it properly. Otherwise, we launch this [very colorful balloon](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bal%C3%A3o_de_ar_quente) in the air, but have no plan to let it fly.

Comment: @TimPost Or they might keep crashing and burning things down, then eventually [become illegal](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balão_de_papel). That's a thing that happens :D

Comment: além do pessoal que cuida da comunidade, vocês também tem aqueles que se dedicam a trazer novos recursos para o SO? tem alguma coisa nova em mente para nós?

Comment: @LeandroRuel Praticamente todo o trabalho das equipes de produto e desenvolvimento tão indo pra Docs, Teams e Jobs. Isso é o que a gente vem preparando já há algum tempo e devem ser lançados em algum ponto esse ano. Depois disso, ainda temos que ver

Comment: Já que não existe previsão de abertura de sites em português, ou de qualquer outra língua diferente do ingles, devidos âs dificuldades anteriormente citadas,  pq a stackexchange não disponibiliza o código e o modelo da base de dados para que desenvolvedores criem seus próprios sites com o modelo Q&A do stackexchanges? Seria um grande avanço.

Comment: @zwitterion Nosso modelo de Q&A não é difícil de replicar. A maior parte da "magia" do nosso código é por questões de desempenho, que precisam existir por conta do nosso tamanho. Tirando isso, clonar o Stack Exchange não é tão complicado. Temos até [uma lista de clones](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2267) no MSE

Comment: Gabe eu lembro de uma palestra que assisti de uma pessoa que trabalhava na stackexchange e falava exatamente sobre a performance, tempo de cada query e etc como fator central do trabalho . Concodo e entendo. Mas o que não entendo é como a abertura de um site excahnge em otro idioma pode afetar a performance geral do stackoverflow por exemplo se estiver numa estrutura física distinta. Quanto aos clones eu   já achei similares, mas nunca o Modelo relacional exato original do stackexcahnge assim como os códigos backend. Frontend devem ser mínimos.Esse post q vc enviou, vou dar uma olhada.

Comment: @zwitterion Não quis dizer que deixamos de abrir sites internacionais por conta de desempenho. O que eu quis dizer é que clonar nosso site não é tão complexo. Grande parte da estrutura relacional tá até no [Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com). Nosso código não é complicado, tirando pelas partes de desempenho.