# O que é o Stackoverflow Documentation?

Tags: suporte, documentação

Apareceu uma nova funcionalidade no Stackoverflow gringo chamada [Documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation), veja:

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

Eu gostaria de saber o que é e se vamos ter aqui no SOpt também?

=D

Comment: **Relacionado:** Pelo jeito não teremos mais https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6230/3635

Answer (score 20):

Se vamos ter aqui eu não sei, duvido que a própria SE saiba no dia de hoje (ver data abaixo).

A SE viu uma "falha" no mecanismo atual e uma necessidade existente. O Q&A é ótimo para dúvidas específicas. Mas não é um formato tão bom para montar documentação de APIs e outras coisas. E ter uma forma colaborativa de montar documentação é algo muito interessante para todos, incluindo produtores de API e também para o próprio Q&A da SE que muitas vezes precisa *linkar* para uma documentação. Documentação que não existe, que está desatualizada, que deixa de existir, pelo menos naquele endereço *linkado*, entre outros problemas.

Por que não usar o *know how* adquirido com a gamificação do Q&A para fazer algo semelhante para a documentação? Daí nasceu o SO Docs.

Parte do mecanismo é o mesmo ou bem parecido, parte é novidade, mas lembra um pouco a dinâmica que já conhecemos.

A ideia dele é ter aquelas páginas de documentação mesmo. Pelo que percebi terá textos, mas o principal será o uso de exemplos de fazer alguma coisa. Receitinha de bolo.

A tendência é que vários projetos o adote com auxiliar ou deixe toda documentação no SO Doc.

É útil e ajudará evitar duplicatas no Q&A. Acho que a tendência é o Docs ter mais "o que fazer" e o Q&A ter mais o "porque fazer".

Gosto da ideia de ser mais colaborativo que o Q&A. Vamos ver o quanto dará certo. Seria bom. Está no caminho certo, aparentemente.

Tomara que dê muito certo e depois venham outras variantes para outros tipos de conteúdo que não se encaixam nem no Q&A, nem no Docs.

Comment: Pois é, várias respostas linkadas para o mesmo pedaço de documentação = bom mecanismo para encontrar perguntas duplicadas (eu tentei fazer isso usando links do JDK na época que o SOen estava promovendo a faxina). Tomará que em algum ponto, quando o *Documentation* estiver mais maduro, promovam um mutirão para linkar respostas antigas com documentação (seria lindo para limpar o site)

Comment: Será que poderia ser mais específico? Li ambas respostas e ainda não entendi como ele será utilizado. Será com base nas respostas que o site já contém? Possuo criar um DOC de uma API pessoal no site? Seria possível fazer um breve esclarecimento do que é e não como surgiu? Falo isso pois eu senti uma dificuldade em entender essas questões.

Comment: @Randrade mostrando em termos do que já conhece, é isto aqui: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring(v=vs.110).aspx Só que será criado colaborativamente e terá gamificação. Parece que está havendo algum controle inicial (pelo que entendi só pode criar novas *tags* no Docs se ela já existir com expressividade no Q&A), mas pode mudar depois para você criar uma documentação da sua API (talvez desde que tenha um mínimo de demanda no Q&A). O fato que nem eles sabem ainda totalmente como vai funcionar. O beta está servindo para ver o que funciona ou não.

Comment: Mesmo depois muita melhoria ainda virá. Obviamente eles serão mais cuidadosos no começo. Qualquer coisa muito detalhada que se fale agora pode ficar defasada. Tem alguma dúvida específica? Já leu o blob? http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2016/07/introducing-stack-overflow-documentation-beta/

Comment: Obrigado por esclarecer. Eu li o blog sim, mas ele me deu mais dúvidas ainda, por isso as perguntas. Só mais uma dúvida... No blog e na documentação, o "show" são os exemplos. Esses exemplos são perguntas já contidas no SO ou são "recriados" no DOC?

Comment: @Randrade acho q não, pelo que vi vc cria um tópico e posta o conteúdo ensinando e explicando alguma coisa.

Comment: @Randrade não sei de que show está falando. O Docs é algo de certa forma separado e diferente. É uma coisa mais estruturada, é para criar páginas de documentação como essa da MS que eu *linkei* aí em cima. Aí vc pode ter algo mais completo, mais atualizado (mantendo diferença pra versões), fica garantido que sempre estará disponível. Não é algo novo, é só uma forma nova de fazer, como aconteceu com o Q&A era. Eles terão vida própria. O que certamente vai acontecer é as pessoas *linkarem* nas suas respostas do Q&A pra eles sempre que possível.

Comment: @bigown Valeu pela explicação. Só explicando, utilizei o termo "show" pois o mesmo está no link do blog sobre a notícia.

Comment: Exemplo de uso de integração entre Q&A e Docs já aqui no SOpt: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/142150/101

Answer (score 7):

O bigown [explicou](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5183) muito bem:

> A SE viu uma "falha" no mecanismo atual e uma necessidade existente. O Q&A é ótimo para dúvidas específicas. Mas não é um formato tão bom para montar documentação de APIs e outras coisas. E ter uma forma colaborativa de montar documentação é algo muito interessante para todos, incluindo produtores de API e também para o próprio Q&A da SE que muitas vezes precisa linkar para uma documentação.

A primeira parte, sobre nós ainda não sabermos se teremos aqui também, é verdade. Infelizmente, há uma [série de coisas que ainda não resolvemos](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4996) sobre como manter os sites internacionais funcionando. Não são problemas fáceis de resolver e adicionar mais coisas internacionais - seja Docs, Jobs, Teams, etc - só dificultaria a solução dos problemas.

Continuamos tentando consertar todos esses problemas, mas leva tempo. E até lá, não temos como dar uma resposta mais exata do que "provavelmente, um dia".

## Atualização

Stack Overflow Docs é o tema do segundo [Estado da Pilha](https://stackoverflow.blog/2016/11/Estado-da-Pilha-Internacional-Novembro-2016/). Eu entro em mais detalhes sobre o que atravanca a habilitação do Docs no SOpt, como a tradução do site **precisa** ser resolvida se quisermos que ele continue se expandindo.

Tentei ser o mais claro o possível, considerando que é uma situação pra qual não temos resposta, e espero que possa ajudar vocês a entenderem melhor a situação do Docs. Além disso, estamos sempre abertos à sugestões. Se você tem alguma ideia do que pode ser feito pra melhorar o site, os comentários aqui embaixo (ou no blog) estão abertos!

Comment: Será que poderia ser mais específico? Li ambas respostas e ainda não entendi como ele será utilizado. Será com base nas respostas que o site já contém? Possuo criar um DOC de uma API pessoal no site? Seria possível fazer um breve esclarecimento do que é e não como surgiu? Falo isso pois eu senti uma dificuldade em entender essas questões.

Comment: Será documentada apenas APIs ou outras tecnologias e ferramentas também serão documentadas?

Comment: @DenerCarvalho APIs, linguagens, programas, bibliotecas... O escopo é tão grande, se não maior, que o do SO

Comment: A pergunta e as respostas são de julho. Houve atualização sobre o assunto?

Comment: @TomásBarcellos Sim. Vai ser o assunto do Estado da Pilha desse mês. Hoje mais tarde eu tenho o link.

Comment: @TomásBarcellos Segunda-feira, na verdade

Comment: @TomásBarcellos Atualização feita!

Comment: @Gabe cada vez que você edita esse post, eu venho correndo achando que o docs está disponivel pra gente kkkk

Comment: @diegofm Se serve pra acalmar seu coração, quando o Docs for disponibilizado, o anúncio vai ser feito separado, e não com um update aqui. Só lembrando que não há previsão nenhuma

Answer (score 5):

> Eu gostaria de saber o que é e se vamos ter aqui no SOpt também?

## NÃO

O Documentation foi um experimento feito pelo SOen que falhou [e será desligado no dia 08/08/2017](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354217/sunsetting-documentation).

Comment: No SOen deveria estar no boletim da comunidade esse discussão. :O

Comment: @rray [Adicionaram a meta-tag featured lá](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/354217/6).