# Inclusão de Documentation e Jobs quando chegar a nova barra de ferramentas

Tags: debate, novo-recurso, menu

Ia postar uma sugestão de novo recurso no Metão, mas acho mais interessante fazer um estudo localizado da idéia. Em algum momento, a [nova barra de menu](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349204/has-the-top-bar-redesign-met-its-goals) deve chegar por aqui. Atualmente não temos atalhos para [*Jobs*](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?med=site-ui&ref=jobs-tab) ou [*Documentation*](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation) em outros sites que não sejam o Stack Overflow.

Basicamente seria isto:

[image: maquete da nova barra no sopt]

A sugestão é adicionar os dois links em todos os [sites de tecnologia](https://stackexchange.com/sites#technology-questionsperday). Como são dois sites em Inglês, nem precisaria traduzir no menu.

Acham esses links adequados se o novo menu chegar ao SOpt?

Comment: Não tenho opinião formada e não sei se o que acharmos vai influenciar alguma coisa.

Answer (score 3):

Quanto ao Documentation, esqueça. [Ele será desligado no dia 08/08/2017](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354217/sunsetting-documentation). Assim sendo, não tem qualquer sentido portá-lo para o SOpt.

Comment: Por isso que é complicado trazer as coisas para os sites internacionais imediatamente. Não temos como saber o destino das coisas

Answer (score 1):

A SE decidiu não colocar o que não está disponível pra gente, o que é coerente. Duvido que alguém discordará.

Quando tiver o Docs, será incluso, se um dia tiver o Jobs, também será.