# Primeira Assembleia Overflow - 12/07/2017

Tags: debate, chat, assembleia-overflow

Na próxima quarta-feira, dia 12/07/2017, vamos ter nossa primeira Assembleia Overflow.

O [@Juan M](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/26473/juan-m), CM do SOes e recém-promovido a líder da equipe de sites internacionais, vai passar um tempo no nosso chat conversando com vocês sobre o SOpt. De onde viemos, para onde vamos, e como vamos chegar lá.

Para manter a organização, faremos um chat moderado. Então é importante que vocês tenham suas perguntas já preparadas, e façam o possível para se ater ao tema. É a oportunidade de perguntarem coisas mais profundas e importantes sobre o papel do nosso site, como ele é gerenciado e quais são nossos planos para o futuro dele. Então aproveitem.

### Assembleia Overflow

- **Quando**:12/07/2017 **-** 13:00 BRT **|** 17:00 WEST **|** 16:00 UTC
- **Tema**: O Papel e o Futuro dos SO Internacionais
- **Quem**: Juan M e Gabe

Deixem suas perguntas abaixo, e votem nas suas favoritas. Vamos usar algumas das melhores perguntas para dar início ao debate, e depois seguir o fluxo que a conversa levar. Vocês também poderão perguntar durante a Assembleia, mas lembrem-se de que temos um tempo limitado, então não será possível responder a tudo que aparecer.

Então, o que gostariam de saber?

---

## Atualização

### Formato

A Assembleia vai ocorrer simultaneamente em duas salas de chat.

A primeira: [Assembleia Overflow - Perguntas](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62052), onde vocês vão poder participar livremente, comentando e debatendo as perguntas e respostas feitas. Essa sala será acompanhada por mim e os moderadores, que levaremos as perguntas para o Juan na outra sala.

Essa outra sala é a [Assembleia Overflow - Respostas](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62056/assembleia-overflow-respostas). A participação lá é restrita aos moderadores e equipe de comunidade, e é lá que eu e o Juan vamos falar sobre o que vocês perguntarem, com os moderadores podendo trazer seus questionamentos e comentários.

Esse é um formato de teste, que leva em consideração a barreira linguística que precisamos superar. Mas podemos adaptá-lo e melhorá-lo para eventos futuros.

Lembrem-se de manter a organização e principalmente a civilidade durante a Assembleia. Vamos fazer o nosso possível para responder às perguntas de forma honesta e aberta, e esperamos que aproveitem!

Comment: Todo mundo poderá ler as mensagens? O "moderado" que você diz é na questão de escrever no chat, certo?

Comment: @Renan Exato. As respostas serão todas públicas, mas a sala será mantida restrita para evitar uma avalanche de mensagens.

Comment: Terá como a gente votar nas perguntas de quem não for restrito?

Comment: @EMBarbosa Ninguém é "restrito". O que eu quis dizer é que na sala onde o Juan e eu iremos responder, a participação será restrita aos moderadores. As perguntas virão de outra sala, onde todos podem participar

Comment: @Gabe ahhh então vai ser do jeito que eu tinha imaginado. Legal!

Comment: Uma duvida que fiquei sobre a Assembleia, ou então eu que me perdi... Então serão dois chats? Um chat somente com você, os mod e o Juan onde serão feitas as perguntas a ele, e o [estouro-de-pilha](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11910/estouro-de-pilha)?

Comment: @MarceloBoni Vai ser num esquema "perguntas da plateia". Eu ainda estou resolvendo os esquemas e espero colocar as instruções aqui amanhã, mas o mais provável é que sejam criadas 2 salas de chat: uma para envio de perguntas e comentários, e outra onde nós vamos apresentar as perguntas e respondê-las. Não sei se é o formato ideal, mas prefiro começar devagar, e ver o que acontece 

Answer (score 31):

Quando receberemos mais swags?

Ex: Camisetas, canecas, adesivos, bonés, chaveiros, porta-copos, porta-celulares, porta-papel, porta-caneta, etc..

Comment: Será que essa pergunta é pro Juan ou é pro Gabe? :P

Comment: É pra quem atendê-la.

Answer (score 28):

Antes de o SOpt ser criado, muita gente era contra os sites internacionais, dizendo que tirariam usuários do SO principal. Eu disse em algum lugar que não achava que isso fosse acontecer, que eu pelo menos continuaria participando dos dois. Mas eu estava errado, realmente acabei me afastando no SO e focando no SOpt.

Pergunta: existem estatísticas sobre o impacto dos sites internacionais no principal, em termos de número de perguntas, número de usuários, ou outros pontos que acharem relevantes?

Comment: Na verdade, há gente que continua criticando até hoje. Quase todas as críticas partem do pressuposto que todos deveriam aprender inglês fluente antes de escrever qualquer *Hello World* ou que as versões em outras línguas são traduções do conteúdo do SOen.

Comment: Adorei essa pergunta, sinto muito isso também.

Comment: Eu acredito que já li algo a respeito mostrando que houve um crescimento além do normal do SOen. Só não me lembro onde.

Comment: Meu caso já foi ao contrário, tentei algumas perguntas no SO, mais rapidamente elas eram fechadas e não conseguia me expressar da forma que desejava, pois meu inglês era péssimo (ainda não é muito melhor). Até que pesquisando soluções para problemas no SO me deparei com o banner do SOpt, comecei a participar aqui e entendi como a comunidade se comportava, como eu deviria me fazer entender e hoje aos poucos estou utilizando o SO até com mais frequência para fazer perguntas que o próprio SOpt, pois muitas das minhas duvidas atuais dificilmente teria uma resposta no SOpt. =D

Comment: @Fernando Não subestime nosso SOpt! :) Tem muita coisa aqui com resposta melhor que no SO em inglês.

Comment: @bfavaretto, com certeza, mas estou falando baseado e algumas experiências que já tive em perguntas que publiquei aqui e depois tive que recorrer ao SO. Por exemplo: [SOpt](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/156005/2998) e [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39798231/2290538) e também essa que tem grande diferença de atenção no [SOpt](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/121960/2998) e [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36475626/2290538). Atualmente se verificar [meu perfil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2290538/fernando?tab=questions&sort=votes) muitas estou postando só lá já.

Answer (score 25):

Teria alguma possibilidade de melhorar a ferramenta de tradução do site? Hoje temos um grande problema ao tentar traduzir usando o transifex pois existem várias strings soltas lá e a tradução depende do seu contexto.

Comment: Relacionado: [Como ajudar quem traduz o site?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4764/3117)

Comment: Eu diria: existe alguma chance de o SO implementar uma ferramenta própria de tradução, nem que seja usando a API do transifex, mas buscando uma interface mais focada nos problemas que temos?

Answer (score 24):

Existem perspectivas para um comportamento mais uniforme entre os SOs internacionais e o principal - por exemplo contendo o Developer Jobs e Documentation?

Comment: Eu fiz uma [pergunta sobre o Documentation](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5182/o-que-%C3%A9-o-stackoverflow-documentation) :D.

Answer (score 24):

Quando poderemos ter o nosso SUpt, caso não seja possível, qual os motivos dessa impossibilidade?

Answer (score 22):

Acredito, talvez, digo talvez, que o *layout* do chat deve caber em um disquete. Nosso chat será melhorado ou continuará com essa aparência/funcionalidade de 1998?

Comment: Kkkkkkkkkkkkkk queria votar 100 vezes nessa pergunta xD

Comment: O chat atual é tosco, mas não quero que um novo ocupe 1.44 MB só de layout ;)

Comment: @bfavaretto mal vai caber num disquete!

Comment: @bfavaretto você usa o chat? :D

Comment: acklay eu gosto do chat como é, simples.

Comment: @JorgeB. Diariamente hahahahaha!

Comment: @JorgeB. também gosto do simples, mas tem como ser simples, moderno e funcional ao mesmo tempo! A evolução é importante para a sobrevivência. =D

Answer (score 17):

Existe alguma ideia de melhorar o fluxo de tradução dos sites?

Existem alguns problemas evidentes no nosso fluxo:

1. O tempo de aprovação geralmente demora bastante. Hoje em dia eu tento avisar o Gabe no chat, aí não demora tanto.
2. A nossa página de *strings* não traduzidas não está mais no ar.
3. Nós, usuários comuns, não podemos sugerir alterações em *strings* que já foram revisadas. Tem bastante coisa escrita errada ou que pode ser melhorada e não temos o que fazer quanto a isso.

Comment: Relacionado: [Como ajudar quem traduz o site?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4764/3117)

Answer (score 14):

Quando será que poderemos adquirir merchandise oficial do SO? =)

Comment: "Adquirir"? Nunca. "Receber"? Quem viver verá (a resposta na assembleia) 

Answer (score 8):

Podemos ver as [mudanças que a plataforma vem recebendo](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/59445/140010) no que chamamos de metão.

Nota-se que os primeiros anos havia muita mudança. Isso foi caindo, até que este ano bem pouco é mudado. A empresa considera que a plataforma está madura e não precisa de melhorias, está muito complicado fazer melhorias no código atual, ou há algum outro motivo para a queda da atualizações?

Answer (score 4):

<sub>Apologies for not writing in Portuguese. I can read it but cannot write. So I'd better write in English than do a lousy attempt that would make everyone's eyes bleed.</sub>

In [Internationalization 'State of the Stack' - Stack Overflow edition](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20987/76013), Tim Post stated that:

> After Spanish, it's going to be a bit of time before we're ready to take on another language.

(...)

> When we're ready to start the next language, we will post here, and reach out to the folks that showed interest in the associated proposal. I wish we could do all of them, right now, because of how successful the sites we've completed have been. We'll keep working, and promise to keep folks abreast.

His post dates from back in June 2015. I assume you have plenty of [statistics about international sites](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6163/28073) and some KPIs to track its success/failure. Could you share what is the current feeling in Stack Exchange about how it has been working so far and about committing to more language specific proposals in the network?

---

O Tim Post escreveu, no [Internationalization 'State of the Stack' - Stack Overflow editon](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20987/76013), que:

> Depois do espanhol, vai levar um tempo até que estejamos prontos para uma outra língua.

(...)

> Quando estivermos preparados, vamos colocar aqui, e notificar quem se interessou pela proposta em questão. Os sites internacionais obtém muito sucesso, e gostaria que pudéssemos criá-los para todas as línguas aqui. Vamos continuar trabalhando, e prometo mantê-los atualizados.

Esse post é de junho de 2015. Eu presumo que vocês tenham muitas [estatísticas sobre os sites internacionais](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6163/28073) e índices de performance que usam para avaliá-los. Vocês podem comentar sobre qual o sentimento da empresa sobre o progresso dos sites atuais, e a possível abertura de sites em outras línguas?

Comment: @Gabe Isso é muito gentil com você, obrigado!

Comment: I translated the post. I did my best to capture your intention, but let me know if I missed or misinterpreted somethind

Comment: @Gabe my understanding of Portuguese is not good enough to perceive the subtleties of a translation, but I perceive the same message I wanted to deliver in English :)

Comment: Ok, cool. It's an interesting question and I hope we get time to address it.

Answer (score 0):

## Não podemos remover conteúdo inútil manualmente?

Explicação:

Existe uma automação que identifica conteúdo como lixo e exclui automaticamente. Algumas vezes isso se dá de forma errônea mas esse não é o foco. A questão é que há muito conteúdo que não agrega valor algum e esse tipo de conteúdo não é pego pela automação mas é constantemente encontrado por usuários do site.

Há algum plano para permitir remover esse "conteúdo lixo"?

Exemplo:

- Perguntas abandonadas onde o AP não dá um feedback e normalmente estão "fora do escopo" ou "não clara o suficiente" mas encontram-se ativas sem status de "fechado". Há muitas peguntas desse tipo, principalmente dos 2 primeiros anos do SO-pt.
- Perguntas onde o AP resolve e não diz como resolveu. Normalmente ficam abandonadas e o título é também normalmente incoerente com o contexto e pior que isso, a solução se dispersou para outro assunto que também é uma incógnita.

Esses são apenas 2 exemplos de conteúdo que não agregam nenhum valor e tem muito mais casos.

Não poderíamos remover manualmente e permanentemente esse tipo de conteúdo? Talvez por meio de votação onde a pergunta iria para a fila de análise.

Penso que podemos tolerar, por um tempo, uma pergunta sem valor que fique abondonada por mais de 1 ano (é muito tempo).
É possível também identificar automaticamente as perguntas sem marcação de resolvido e enviar um alerta, email, algo do tipo que chame a atenção do AP.

Enfim, há diversas formas de classificar o que é um conteúdo lixo sem causar equívocos.

*Não vou participar da Assembléia. Apenas quis colocar algo útil.

Comment: Isto não precisa de intervenção da SE. Se o *post* estiver negativado ele será removido. O problema é que as pessoas votam em coisa sem sentido e não gostam de negativar. Mesmo que ainda tenha algumas discrepâncias é possível fazer uma lista do que precisa intervenção manual.

Comment: Isso que coloquei em questão. O modelo atual não serve. Acaba até protegendo o lixo. Deveria ter uma opção "excluir" "conteúdo inútil", algo desse gênero sem precisar de "10 votos" negativos.. Mas quer dizer que não precisa da SE? Como podemos revolver? Eu desconheço.

Comment: Já existe. Conteúdo inútil é o que está negativo. Se está positivo ele não não é inútil. E pode-se votar para remover se tiver reputação para isto, o que entra fica disponível em "fila" para os usuários que sabem usar a ferramenta como um todo. Não precisa de 10 votos negativos, basta estar negativado para a remoção ser automática. Ajuda se estiver fechada. Se tudo isso falhar é possível fazer uma lista manual aqui no meta. O sistema já funciona, basta as pessoas quererem, não precisa pedir para a SE fazer nada.

Comment: 10 votos está entre aspas pois foi só exemplo.. E discordo totalmente disso e é isso que estou colocando. Não serve. Como vc mesmo colocou, muito conteúdo lixo recebe voto positivo. vou apenas mostrar um exemplo de tópico abandonado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/150808. Isso é um mero exemplo e tem coisa pior.
 [sobre a ultima frase] 
Ahh.. saquei. Então basta fazer uma lista e postar manualmente no meta? Claro que as pessoas não vão colaborar porque dá muito trabalho. O ideal é uma opção com um botão. Clica e vai para algum banco automaticamente sem ter esse trabalho todo.

Comment: Tem que considerar que as pessoas não vivem aqui 24horas por dia 7 dias por semana. Muitas pessoas tem vida fora do computador e tem suas ocupações diárias... E sendo chato, insisto que o sistema automatico não funciona bem pois é baseado em votos e não interpreta o conteúdo. Eu mesmo já flagrei conteúdo útil indo para o lixo. E ao mesmo mesmo vejo conteúdo lixo solto, livre e inclusive com votos positivos. é bem difícil ver o conteúdo sendo excluído pois sequer tem fila de análise para fazer uma checagem "humana".