# Em qual idioma fazer a Assembleia Overflow?

Tags: debate, chat, assembleia-overflow

A [Assembleia Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6154) vem aí, e temos uma barreira idiomática a superar.

O Juan fala apenas inglês e espanhol. Então precisamos decidir **qual língua ele deve usar para responder** às perguntas de vocês.

Todas as perguntas podem ser feitas em português, e todas as respostas serão traduzidas ao português. Mas seria interessante que o Juan respondesse na língua que a maioria de vocês tem familiaridade, para ajudar que o maior número de pessoas entenda sem ter que esperar pela tradução.

Então essa pergunta tem duas respostas: **Inglês** e **Espanhol**.

Novamente: **suas perguntas podem ser feitas normalmente em português**. Então votem na sua favorita para **as respostas do Juan**.

Caso você não tenha preferência, por favor não vote em nenhuma. Assim podemos garantir um resultado justo com quem precisa.

### Atualização: Por favor **não votem contra** nas respostas. Tratem essa pergunta como uma simples enquete.

Answer (score 31):

## Gostaria que o Juan respondesse em Inglês

Comment: Parece que isso já foi decidido.

Answer (score 0):

## Gostaria que o Juan respondesse em Espanhol

Comment: Eu acho que não é necessário downvotes, basta upvote na que você desejar, será que o pessoal ainda não aprendeu a fazer um bom uso dos votes neste tipo especifico de postagem? Já foi falado que downvotes não são "contabilizados". Poxa sempre a mesma coisa. (ps: a mensagem não é para o Gabe e sim para quem for dar downvotes :/)

Comment: Não fui eu pois eu percebi o contexto.. é uma gambiarra que simula uma enquete rsrs.. Mas eu entendo o lado de quem o fez pois  o problema aqui é UX. Isso aqui deveria estar no formato de enquete mas foi feito uma enquete nas coxa usando o formato de perguntas e respostas. É mais óbvio que as pessoas confundam e votem negativo. Não é culpa de quem votou negativo. Temos que ter ciência de que nem todos vivem aqui 24 horas por dia e fora isso tem os novatos que não se acostumaram com as gambiarras daqui. Se tem uma falha aqui, é UX, praticamente inexistente.

Comment: E fora isso, ao postar da forma como comentou, @GuilhermeNascimento, vc acaba de ganhar 1 ou 2 desafetos.. rsrsrsr pois tem 2 negativos.. É disso que eu falo. Pela falha na UX, cria-se esses pequenos transtornos que se ramificam ao além e infinito.. rsrsr Não entendo qual a dificuldade do SO criar um sisteminha de enquete. Qualquer muleque iniciando no HTML faz isso em 2 dias. Uma empresa desse porte, renomada mundialmente, com profissionais de alto nível, faz coisas nas coxas grosseiramente.

Comment: Uou - pera lá, @DanielOmine - eu achei engraçado o Guilherme fazer o comentário que fez e, inclusive, fiquei incomodando ele e o Gabe no debate da pilha a respeito disso - mas discordo de você com relação a "nas coxas grosseiramente" - acho possivelmente até prejudicial implementar um sistema de enquetes aqui; já vi sites que quiseram ser "completos" darem errado terrivelmente - tenho absoluta certeza que a falta de enquetes aqui é *status by design*, e concordo totalmente com isso

Comment: Não acho nada de mais fornecer uma enquete.. A questão é mais UX e não "querer ser completo". Quem negativou e levou na boa, tudo bem. É um caso a parte pois a maioria não leva para esse lado sensato. Mas continuo com a opinião de que fazem sim nas coxa coisas simples que não custa nada implementar. Há tantos meios inteligentes de resolver. Se não quer implementar dentro do site, pode fazer um sisteminha separado ou usar um serviço terceiro. Enfim, é questão de ter vontade. Mas isso tudo é alheio ao foco da questão. Foi apenas observação ao comentário.