# Assembleia Overflow #001 (JuanM) - Compilação

Tags: debate, assembleia-overflow

Aqui estão as respostas, traduzidas e organizadas, das perguntas feitas durante a [Assembleia Overflow #001](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6154) com [@Juan M](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/26473/juan-m), gerente da equipe de sites internacionais.

Vocês podem ler o chat inteiro com as perguntas aqui: [Assembleia Overflow #001 - Perguntas](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62052/conversation/assembleia-overflow-001-juanm-perguntas).
O histórico das nossas respostas está aqui: [Assembleia Overflow #001 - Respostas](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62056/conversation/assembleia-overflow-001-juanm-respostas).

Answer (score 18):

## Pergunta:

> Quando receberemos mais swags?
>
> Ex: Camisetas, canecas, adesivos, bonés, chaveiros, porta-copos, porta-celulares, porta-papel, porta-caneta, etc..

- [@Math](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6164)

## Resposta

> O que aconteceu no último ano foi que tivemos diversos problemas com a alfândega do Brasil, e decidimos começar a fabricar as coisas no Brasil. Isso levou bastante tempo, até encontrarmos uma empresa que fabricasse, armazenasse, e enviasse os produtos quando necessário.
>
> Eu liguei pra aproximadamente mil empresas de brindes e depois de um tempo consegui encontrar uma que fizesse tudo. A partir daí, nosso problema passou a ser conseguir encontrar uma maneira prática de pagar pelos envios, porque as empresas de envio não atuam no Brasil a não ser que tenhamos uma entidade empresarial no país, para contratá-las.
>
> Entrei em contato com todas as maiores (FedEx, DHL, UPS) e nenhuma delas pode abrir uma conta no Brasil para uma empresa americana. E, no momento estamos tentando resolver esse problema...
>
> Mas acho que temos uma solução - meio gambiarra - para o futuro próximo
> E espero poder começar a enviar brindes antes do final do ano. É isso.

- [@Gabe](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/62056?m=38732354#38732354)

> Quero adicionar que ter brindes para distribuir é algo muito importante para nós. Gostamos de presentear nossas comunidades com coisas bacanas e vamos continuar tentando encontrar uma maneira de fazer isso.
>
> Por enquanto, gostaria que vocês soubessem que temos a possibilidade de fazer camisetas especiais para cada um dos nossos sites internacionais. Então podemos dar às camisetas a "nossa cara". Por exemplo as camisetas para a graduação do SOes, que vocês podem [ver aqui](https://twitter.com/SoyJuanMacias/status/884523204240396288).
>
> Também estamos tentando fazer canecas e outras coisas ;)
> Fiquem de olho!

- [@JuanM](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/62056?m=38732538#38732538)

---

---

## Pergunta

> Antes de o SOpt ser criado, muita gente era contra os sites internacionais, dizendo que tirariam usuários do SO principal. Eu disse em algum lugar que não achava que isso fosse acontecer, que eu pelo menos continuaria participando dos dois. Mas eu estava errado, realmente acabei me afastando no SO e focando no SOpt.
>
> Pergunta: existem estatísticas sobre o impacto dos sites internacionais no principal, em termos de número de perguntas, número de usuários, ou outros pontos que acharem relevantes?

- [@bfavaretto](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6163)

## Resposta

> Boa pergunta! Os sites internacionais são valiosos para a empresa, e vem se tornando mais importantes à medida que crescem.
>
> Uma estatística interessantes é que, atualmente, em torno de 32% dos visitantes do SOen não tem inglês como a língua do seu navegador. Isso significa que existem MUITAS pessoas que ainda não estamos servindo, e gostaríamos de mudar isso.
>
> Nós tivemos sucesso em criar bons lugares para pessoas poderem participar em suas línguas nativas, mas muitos ainda não sabem da existência desses sites. Isso me incomoda, e é algo que os CMs Internacionais vão tentar resolver no futuro próximo.
>
> Outro número interessante é que o SOru se encontra em 4 lugar em Perguntas/Dia, com o SOpt e o SOes se aproximando. Todos esses se encontram no Top 10, e chegarão ao Top 5 no futuro próximo, no ritmo atual.
>
> Mas, sim, os sites internacionais são importantes e vamos continuar trabalhando o máximo para que eles cresçam e continuem melhorando, de maneira a servir vocês o melhor possível.

- [@JuanM](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/38732643#38732643)

> Para complementar, e eu posso mostrar gráfico mais tarde, a atividade no SOen não caiu desde a abertura do Internacionais. Tudo que eles fizeram foi permitir que gente que não participava antes pudesse participar agora.
>
> Nós, basicamente, criamos novos usuários. E movemos alguns para sites em que eles participam mais.

- [@Gabe](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/38732962#38732962)

---

---

## Pergunta

> Existem perspetivas para um comportamento mais uniforme entre os SOs internacionais e o principal - por exemplo contendo o Developer Jobs e Documentation?

- [@OnoSendai](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6158)

## Resposta

> Meu objetivo é ter Jobs em todos os sites internacionais. Acho que oferecer isso às comunidades é extremamente importante e vai nos ajudar de várias maneiras. No entanto, antes de conseguir fazer isso, é preciso demonstrar para a empresa que estamos crescendo, engajando e ajudando nossas comunidades. As formas de medir isso variam, mas vamos sempre monitorar esses números.
>
> O que precisamos de vocês é exatamente isso - que continuem participando e crescendo. Quanto mais demonstrarmos que somos parte ativa da comunidade de desenvolvedores, e que estamos trazendo pessoas para os nossos sites, mais visibilidade vamos ter na empresa, e melhores as chances de trazer essas funcionalidades para vocês. Em resumo, não faz parte do plano incluir essas coisas nos Internacionais por enquanto. Mas quanto antes demonstrarmos que podemos nos beneficiar delas, melhor.

- [@JuanM](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/62056?m=38733169#38733169)

---

---

## Pergunta

> Teria alguma possibilidade de melhorar a ferramenta de tradução do site? Hoje temos um grande problema ao tentar traduzir usando o transifex pois existem várias strings soltas lá e a tradução depende do seu contexto.

- [@Math](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6162)

## Resposta

> [O Juan] me respondeu pelo hangout sobre essa pergunta, disse que a curto prazo não veem uma nova ferramenta tomando o lugar do transifex, o que pode ser feito e que ele vai tentar fazer é usar a tag para indicar quais strings são mais importantes pois tem muita string que entra no sistema sendo que a interface nem esta implementada ainda, e as vezes nunca é
>
> Então hoje se olhar o backlog de tradução ele está gigante, mas o problema na verdade não é tanto assim pois grande parte do que está lá não está em produção

- [@Math](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/62056?m=38733269#38733269)

---

---

## Pergunta

> Se der tempo, seria legal dele comentar sobre diferenças de escopo entre os internacionais e o SO, e também dos internacionais entre si

- [@bfavaretto](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/62052?m=38733267#38733267)

## Resposta

> A primeira parte é a diferença entre as responsabilidades do CMs do SO, e dos Internacionais. A segunda é sobre a diferença entre as responsabilidades dentro do Time Internacional.
>
> Sobre a primeira parte, os CMs do SO lidam com diversos assuntos relacionados a centenas de sites, mensagens de suporte, os Metas,  discussões com moderadores, entre outras coisas. Já os CMs Internacionais tem responsabilidades mais amplas, porque somos um só - realizando vários trabalhos. Somos responsáveis, entre outras coisas, por nossos:
>
> 1. Usuários
> 2. Metas
> 3. Suporte
> 4. Traduções
> 5. Métricas
> 6. Moderadores
> 7. Mídias sociais
> 8. Marketing
> 9. Design, produção, armazenamento e envio dos nossos brindes
>
> É bastante, como podem ver. Precisamos assumir diversos papeis ao longo do dia, dependendo do projeto em que estamos trabalhando. Temos recursos limitados e precisamos ser criativos para conseguir fazer as coisas, especialmente no que envolve outros departamentos. É parte do desafio, e a empresa fornece ajuda quando necessário, mas no final das contas a comunidade depende da participação de vocês: moderando, editando, e trabalhando para manter a qualidade do site.
>
> Não poderíamos fazer nosso trabalho sem vocês. Essas comunidades são suas e adoramos ver o cuidado que vocês tem com elas, moldando-as de acordo com as necessidades de cada cultura.
>
> Como vocês sabem, cada comunidade tem necessidades diferentes. Somos um experimento muito interessante de cultura global. Os sites em português e espanhol são muito similares, pela proximidade. E o japonês e o russo tem cada um seu jeito de ser.
>
> Tocando no escopo do site, cada um deles tem seu próprio foco e tentamos permitir que a comunidade tome a direção que quiser. No SOes, por exemplo, não são permitidas coisas fora do escopo mas já aconteceu de abrirmos espaço para questões menos formais, e mais abertas. Mas isso não deve continuar acontecendo no futuro.
>
> Um jeito fácil de saber o que é importante para a comunidade é olhar para as tags mais populares. Você acaba tendo uma boa noção do que mais interessa à comunidade.
>
> Quanto à perguntas do tipo SU, o SOes vem aceitando-as por enquanto, já que não temos um SUes - mas elas são moderadas de perto, já que podem sair do escopo com facilidade. Acredito que nem o SOjp, nem o SOru, permitam perguntas assim, mas decidimos tentar no SOes. Por que não? Vamos ver o que acontece.
>
> **Eu disse à comunidade que ela não é um clone do SOen, e que ela deve se tornar o que precisar ser**.

- [@JuanM](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/62056?m=38733461#38733461)

> A mensagem que a gente passa para os sites internacionais, na abertura deles, é sempre a mesma: "Sejam o site que a comunidade de programação do seu país/língua precisa que vocês sejam". É daí que vem o princípio de não clonar o SOen.
>
> Ou, se for pra copiar o SOen, copiem justamente o senso de experimentação e necessidade que fez o escopo dele mudar tanto ao longo de 9 anos. Não adianta tentar definir o escopo final do site no seu primeiro mês, ano, ou 5 anos.
>
> Não existe "objetivo final", no escopo, nem escolha certa ou errada, sobre o escopo. Existe só a necessidade de se ater a um formato básico, e ajudar a comunidade o máximo possível

- [@Gabe](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/62056?m=38733935#38733935)

---

---

## Pergunta

> Quando poderemos ter o nosso SUpt, caso não seja possível, qual os motivos dessa impossibilidade?

- [@JefersonAlmeida](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6160)

## Resposta

> O SUpt foi sugerido algumas vezes ao longo dos anos, chegando a ter uma proposta válida na Área 51. Mas foi rejeitado por nós, até segunda ordem.
>
> Na época da proposta, havia um grande receio da nossa parte quanto à divisão da comunidade, e o uso do SUpt como um refugo do que não queriam no SOpt. Era algo que já tínhamos visto e lidado em outras comunidades, e que gostaríamos de evitar aqui. Junto a isso, como o Juan citou acima, o trabalho dos CMs Int é variado, lidando om muitos problemas que os outros CMs não precisam resolver. Gerenciar nossos sites dá bastante trabalho. E não queríamos dar um passo maior que nossas pernas.
>
> Hoje o nosso receio sobre a divisão não existe mais. A comunidade é madura e grande o suficiente, sem problemas. Mas o problema da nossa habilidade de gerenciar efetivamente um outro site ainda existe.
>
> Um outro site significa um outro projeto de tradução (duplicando os problemas que já temos), mais swag (que já temos problemas), mais iniciativas de marketing (que já são difíceis de encaixar), e mais responsabilidade sobre o futuro de um site que representa e ajuda uma nova comunidade.
>
> O mesmo desconhecimento sobre o Stack Overflow, por parte de pessoas de outros lugares, que nos levou a abrir os SO Internacionais existe na comunidade de SysAdmins, ou Power Users. Temos que nos preparar da mesma maneira para dar o melhor apoio possível a ela, e no momento não temos como fazer isso.
>
> Nós levamos os internacionais à sério. SO, SU, ou SF. E a melhor maneira de ter certeza de que o SUpt será bem servido é evitando criá-lo sem condições de dar todo o suporte necessário ao seu sucesso.
>
> Um assunto paralelo a esse, levantado pelo [@MagicHat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/38734292#38734292) é que uma das maneiras de ajudar a comunidade de SysAdmins e Power Users é criar formas de aceitar no SOpt algumas perguntas que caberiam nos outros sites. Foi o que aconteceu no SOen por anos, até a criação da Trilogia.
>
> Não há nada de errado nisso, e pode tranquilamente ser feito de maneira responsável e útil à comunidade. Mas é preciso que a comunidade, vocês, debatam isso aberta e seriamente, para ver se é o que gostariam e, se for o caso, qual a melhor maneira de fazê-lo.

- [@Gabe](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/62056?m=38734260#38734260)

Comment: Ótimas respostas, bem esclarecedora, principalmente no que tange as razões do supt não ter ido pra frente. Eu como membro "novo" não peguei esse período, e como poucos sabiam a respeito, a razões ficavam meio nebulosas.

Comment: Acho q finalmente deu pra eu entender o trabalho de vocês, CMs. Pode parecer engraçado mas sempre achei que o trabalho de vocês eram o mesmo dos moderadores eleitos, só que com alguns "super poderes" para moderar além deles. E é bem mais do que isso, o que até justifica não vermos muito o Gabe com frequência no chat ou aqui no meta.

Comment: Gostei muito da ideia do SOpt conversar sobre aceitar perguntas do mundo SysAdmins e Power Users.