# Assembleia Overflow #001 - Comentários e Sugestões

Tags: debate, assembleia-overflow

A primeira [Assembleia Overflow #001](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6154), com [@Juan M](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/26473/juan-m), aconteceu há duas semanas. Fizemos o nosso melhor para responder ao máximo de perguntas, da melhor maneira possível, e acredito que vocês tenham gostado do evento.

Apesar do sucesso da primeira tentativa gostaríamos de aperfeiçoar onde for necessário, para que as próximas assembleias sejam ainda melhores.

O maior desafio, quando tivermos um convidado, será a barreira linguística. Apenas 4 pessoas no Stack falam português, e só uma delas trabalha com sites internacionais (esse que vos fala). Assim, sempre que a comunidade quiser ouvir de pessoas como [Tim Post](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/10/), [Shog9](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/6/shog9), [Jay Hanlon](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/14/jaydles), [Hairboat](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/7/hairboat), ou qualquer um dos outros envolvidos no Stack Overflow, vamos precisar superar essa barreira.

Então queria saber o que vocês acharam. Ficaram felizes com as respostas? O evento fluiu bem? Sentiram falta de alguma coisa?

Quais são as sugestões que vocês tem para melhorarmos a Assembleia, e ela seja ainda mais proveitosa no futuro?

Que outros convidados gostariam de ter? O que acham de talvez não termos sempre um convidado, e eu responder às perguntas de vocês?

Enfim, há muito que ser pensado sobre as Assembleias. Eu acredito que elas são muito importantes para aproximar o SOpt do resto da companhia e quanto melhor elas funcionarem, mais vocês vão se beneficiar dessas oportunidades.

O que acham?

---

Só lembrando:
Vocês podem ler o chat inteiro com as perguntas aqui: [Assembleia Overflow #001 - Perguntas](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62052/conversation/assembleia-overflow-001-juanm-perguntas).
O histórico das nossas respostas está aqui: [Assembleia Overflow #001 - Respostas](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62056/conversation/assembleia-overflow-001-juanm-respostas).
E a compilação de tudo que foi dito aqui: [Assembleia Overflow #001 (JuanM) - Compilação](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6183/)

Comment: Quem é o 4o. que eu não sei? :) Eu perdi o evento or problema técnicos, não sei como ele aconteceu e o que poderia melhorar. Foi legal ter respostas e vale fazer outras vezes, embora seria legal que as perguntas que já existem no meta sejam respondidas também, aos poucos ou em evento. Não vejo a necessidade de convidados sempre. Podemos pedir para convidar qualquer funcionário, mesmo os técnicos, ou tem que ser só sobre a comunidade? Um dia quem sabe o Joel? :)

Comment: @bigown Eu, JNat, rla4 e uma outra pessoa em Marketing. E da próxima vez eu vou pedir sugestões sobre quem convidar. A ideia é ter 1 desses por trimestre, então não tem pressa pra decidir nada ainda sobre convidados.

Comment: "E da próxima vez eu vou pedir sugestões de quem convidar." -@Gabe. Acho que podia fazer isso até com o Juan já. Perguntar pra ele o que funcionou pra ele, o que ele teve mais dificuldade e se tem alguma sugestão...

Comment: @EMBarbosa Eu já conversei com ele. O que eu quis dizer foi "sugestões *sobre* quem convidar". Vou esclarecer o texto

Comment: Ahh.. Eu interpretei da outra maneira porque no texto principal já está perguntando isso, veja: *"Que outros convidados gostariam de ter?"*

Comment: Além desses usuários citados no post, há também o JNat que sabe português, e ele poderia participar, seria ótimo!

Answer (score 9):

> Ficaram felizes com as respostas? O evento fluiu bem?

Não sabia bem o que esperar da assembléia mas gostei que ela tenha ocorrido e também gostei da maioria das respostas. As vezes os funcionários (incluindo o Gabe) parecem muito distantes da comunidade e pode passar a impressão de que não estão fazendo nada (sei que estão, mas é uma impressão que *pode* passar `;-)` ), e fazer essas conversas com a comunidade é uma ótima oportunidade de se aproximarem e mostrarem um pouco mais do trabalho de vocês e como estão contribuindo para a comunidade mesmo que não estejam em evidência o tempo todo.

A questão não é cobrar o que vocês estão fazendo mas acredito que esses eventos são tipo um *behind the scenes* que podem cativar a comunidade e incentivar mais a participação dos usuários na comunidade.

> Quais são as sugestões que vocês tem para melhorarmos a Assembleia, e ela seja ainda mais proveitosa no futuro?

Não sei se todo mundo sabe mas eu tive a oportunidade de participar do hangout da assembleia onde estavam presentes o Gabe, o Juan e eu. Eu achei bem interessante participar e poder ver e ouvir os envolvidos discutindo os assuntos levantados para a assembleia, e acredito que mais usuários também gostariam de poder participar dessa maneira, sem deixar de lado a parte do chat escrito que é ótimo para ter um registro em forma de texto e pra quem não pode ficar com uma tela de conferência aberta enquanto ele ocorre.

Minha pergunta é, é possível que mais pessoas participem desse hangout e que possam conversar com os convidados? Caso não seja interessante fazer assim ou haja um limite de usuários, teria como transmiti-la para quem quiser assistir?

É minha opinião, mas seria legal ver se tem mais gente que gosta dessa ideia para ver se vale a pena correr atrás dessa estrutura.

> Que outros convidados gostariam de ter? O que acham de talvez não termos sempre um convidado, e eu responder às perguntas de vocês?

Acho que convidados são interessantes sim, não tenho um nome em mente, acho que qualquer um que pudesse dar o ar da graça e participar assim seria bem interessante.

Não vejo bem como seria uma assembléia apenas com você (Gabe), pois isso teoricamente pode ser feito no dia a dia com qualquer usuário criando uma pergunta no meta direcionada a você, por isso que acho que a participação de quem nunca dá as caras por aqui poderia ser interessante.

Reforçando que essa é a minha opinião, digam se concordam com os pontos que citei aqui ou não.

Comment: Concordo com tudo. Inclusive acho que a Assembleia podia até ter um espaço de tempo maior (4 em 4 meses, por exemplo) se isso fosse necessário pra ter sempre um convidado. Ahh, e sempre ter um post no meta com as perguntas e respostas.

Comment: @EMBarbosa O tempo maior entre elas ajuda mais para termos certeza de que sempre vai haver interesse e assunto, do que necessariamente dificuldade em encontrar um convidado.

Comment: @Gabe O que é **muito válido**, em minha opinião. Melhor um evento semi anual muito aguardado do que um mensal que ninguém dá atenção. :)

Comment: Gostei da ideia do hangout ;) Mas seria em português o hangout?

Comment: @gato infelizmente não para a maioria dos casos, acho que só o JNat que fala português, daí entra na barreira da língua que o Gabe citou na pergunta. Uma possível solução seria quem não fala inglês apenas assistir e contarmos com um closed caption traduzido em tempo real, igual acho q o YouTube tem. Mais um motivo para a vídeo conferência não ser capaz de substituir o chat, seria só um plus pra quem quisesse acompanhar.