# Como são criadas novas comunidades?

Tags: novo-recurso

Existem assuntos que acredito que várias pessoas possuem dúvidas e gostaria de debater sobre, então gostaria de saber 
como uma nova comunidade é criada.

Comment: [Aqui](https://area51.stackexchange.com/). Geralmente uma proposta precisa de muitos membros, uma discussão sensata e uma ideia concreta o suficiente para dar certo, as vezes nem isso basta, muitas vezes uma comunidade nasce Beta e morre Beta. A rede Stack Exchange tem bastante [variedade de comunidades](https://stackexchange.com/sites). Agora, cursiosidade, de qual comunidade você precisa? :)

Comment: Acho que começa pela [Área 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/). Nunca fiz parte de lá, nunca vi nada lá, não sei como funciona. Eu sei que há uma resistência para se criar regionalizações de outras coisas na rede SE que não sejam específicas de língua (como o [Portugues Language](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/)) ou derivadas do Stack Overflow (como o [Stack Overflow em Russo](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/))

Comment: Relacionada: [Outros sites da rede StackExchange não poderiam ter a versão em português?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4996/91)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isto é feito no site https://area51.stackexchange.com/

Mas não quer dizer que vai ser aprovado, também não quer dizer que isto tenha alguma ligação com o SOpt ou com o SOen, seria uma comunidade totalmente a parte

Existem critérios para ser aprovado, primeiro tem que alcançar o numero de "commits" necessários, depois provavelmente moderadores globais e staff (da empresa) vão avaliar se realmente aquilo é necessário e ai sim seria lançado um Beta

Uma dica, provavelmente comunidades em idiomas específicos raramente são aprovados, teria que ser algo internacional (ou seja inglês), para ser interessante para a "empresa Stack Overflow" (não confundir com os sites https://stackoverflow.com e https://pt.stackoverflow.com), claro que existem exceções que foram em idiomas específicos, mas isto é devido a necessidade especificas, como:

- https://pt.stackoverflow.com
- https://ja.stackoverflow.com
- https://es.stackoverflow.com
- https://ru.stackoverflow.com

Um exemplo que não deu certo foi o superuser em português, veja os detalhes em:

- [Super User em Português - Já era no Area 51](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2482/3635)

Note que esta com a tag [status-recusado](/questions/tagged/status-recusado)

Comment: Relevante: https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27938/changes-to-the-area-51-process-v3-0

Comment: @bfavaretto depois vou ler com calma e detalhar aqui (ou na primeira dup) :) Grato!